# T-SQL Insert - Select in Table variable is very slow

Tags: t-sql, variables, select, insert

I have a table variable and I am inserting in it some values using the "Insert Into - Select" statement. The select is a combination of few joins, and when it is executed separately it takes 3 seconds. The problem is that the whole code takes 3-4 minutes to executed. I wonder is there a particular reason for this.

This is the my table variable declaration:

```
DECLARE @Result TABLE 
(
     ProductID NVARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY
    ,ProductName NVARCHAR(100)
    ,ProductCategoryID TINYINT
    ,ProductCategory  NVARCHAR(50)
    ,ProductSubCategoryID TINYINT
    ,ProductSubCategory  NVARCHAR(50)
    ,BrandID TINYINT
    ,Brand  NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

I have an other table variable which I initialize with some data, and this is its structure:

```
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    ProtoSurveyID INT,
    ProductID NVARCHAR(25) PRIMARY KEY
)
```

and the following code is my problem statement (insert into - select):

```
INSERT INTO @Result (ProductID,ProductName,ProductCategoryID,ProductCategory,ProductSubCategoryID,ProductSubCategory,BrandID,Brand)
SELECT 
         Products.ProductID  AS ProductID
        ,Products.ProductName  AS ProductName
        ,ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID  AS ProductCategoryID
        ,ProductCategories.ProductCategory   AS ProductCategory
        ,ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategoryID  AS ProductSubCategoryID
        ,ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategory  AS ProductSubCategory
        ,Brands.BrandID AS BrandID
        ,Brands.Brand  AS Brand
FROM 
(
        SELECT     
               CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS ProductCategoryID
              ,CAST(A.Col002 AS tinyint) AS BrandID
              ,CAST(A.Col003 AS nvarchar(25)) AS ProductID
              ,CAST(A.Col004 AS nvarchar(100)) AS ProductName
              ,CAST(A.Col006 As tinyint) AS ProductSubCategoryID
              ,B.ProtoSurveyID
        FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A 
        INNER JOIN @TempTable B 
        ON B.ProductID=CAST(A.Col003 AS nvarchar(25))
        WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 3 
) Products      
INNER JOIN
(
         SELECT CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS BrandID
              , CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(50)) AS Brand
         FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
         WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 1
)Brands On Products.BrandID=Brands.BrandID
INNER JOIN
(
         SELECT CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS ProductCategoryID
                ,CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(50)) AS ProductCategory
         FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
         WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 2
) ProductCategories On Products.ProductCategoryID=ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID
INNER JOIN
(
         SELECT CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS ProductSubCategoryID
              , CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(50)) AS ProductSubCategory
         FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
         WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 11
) ProductSubCategories on Products.ProductSubCategoryID=ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategoryID
```

As I told before, if I comment the insert line the query takes 3 seconds, otherwise - a very long time.

EDIT: Here is my execution plan - most of the cost is table scan, but why it takes so many time when insert is make, and happens to quick without it?

[image]

The follow is my new inline function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_XxCustom_RetailAudits_GetProductsForFilter]
(
    @SecurityObjectUserID BIGINT
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN

    WITH CTE(ProtoSurveyID,ProductID) AS
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT  CAST(B.ProtoSurveyID AS INT)
                         ,CAST(A.Col002 AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS ProductID
        FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
        JOIN SurveyInstances B ON A.Col001=B.SurveyInstanceID AND CAST(B.ProtoSurveyID AS INT) IN (SELECT ProtoSurveyID FROM dbo.fn_Filter_GetProtoSurveysAllowedShort(@SecurityObjectUserID, 'CLIENTACCESS',NULL))
        WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 5
    )
    SELECT 
             Products.ProductID  AS ProductID
            ,Products.ProductName  AS ProductName
            ,ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID  AS ProductCategoryID
            ,ProductCategories.ProductCategory   AS ProductCategory
            ,ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategoryID  AS ProductSubCategoryID
            ,ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategory  AS ProductSubCategory
            ,Brands.BrandID AS BrandID
            ,Brands.Brand  AS Brand
    FROM 
    (
            SELECT     
                   CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS ProductCategoryID
                  ,CAST(A.Col002 AS tinyint) AS BrandID
                  ,CAST(A.Col003 AS nvarchar(25)) AS ProductID
                  ,CAST(A.Col004 AS nvarchar(100)) AS ProductName
                  ,CAST(A.Col006 As tinyint) AS ProductSubCategoryID
                  ,B.ProtoSurveyID
            FROM CTE B
            INNER JOIN DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A 
            ON B.ProductID=CAST(A.Col003 AS nvarchar(25))
            WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 3 
    ) Products      
    INNER JOIN
    (
             SELECT CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS BrandID
                   ,CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(50)) AS Brand
             FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
             WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 1
    )Brands On Products.BrandID=Brands.BrandID
    INNER JOIN
    (
             SELECT  CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS ProductCategoryID
                    ,CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(50)) AS ProductCategory
             FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
             WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 2
    ) ProductCategories On Products.ProductCategoryID=ProductCategories.ProductCategoryID
    INNER JOIN
    (
             SELECT  CAST(A.Col001 AS tinyint) AS ProductSubCategoryID
                    ,CAST(A.Col002 AS nvarchar(50)) AS ProductSubCategory
             FROM DataSetsMaterializedDataSqlvariant A
             WHERE DataSetsMaterializedInternalRowsetID = 11
    ) ProductSubCategories on Products.ProductSubCategoryID=ProductSubCategories.ProductSubCategoryID

GO
```

I runs slowly again. Any ideas how to optimize it?

Comment: Use Query Analyzer's "explain plan" button to show you where the time is being taken.

Comment: @JeffWatkins I am going to attach screenshot with the execution plan to my question.

Comment: What happens if you select into a temp table?

Comment: @MarkRobinson Do you mean #temp table ?

Comment: The SQL Server query optimizer will always assume that a table variable has exactly one row - this can cause it to use a rather inefficient query plan. A temporary table (`#mytable`) doesn't have that limitation - maybe switching to a "proper" temporary table could help ...

Comment: @marc_s - The OP says the performance of the underlying `SELECT` is OK so it seems to be something specific to the use in the `insert` statement that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Queries that insert into table variables can't have a parallel plan.

Try using a `#temp` table instead to allow the `SELECT` to be parallelised.

Comment: @Joro - Can you rewrite it to be an inline TVF instead rather than a multi statement one? Then that will avoid the need to insert into the intermediate table variable at all. It means you rewrite the query to be a single statement. Using a CTE or derived table to replace the role of `@TempTable`

Comment: @MartinSmith I can use any type of function, but I have thought the only way to return table is this?

Comment: @Joro - No there's two different types of TVF. The inline ones are more efficient as they get inlined by the optimiser but need the logic to be expressible in a single SQL Statement.

Comment: @MartinSmith yes, thank you i get the idea. I will do this. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joro - BTW: Just to check that the original diagnosis was correct when you look at the execution plan for the `SELECT` statement on its own does it actually have a parallel plan?

Comment: @MartinSmith I am sorry, you mean the execution plan of the select statement only? I have create a inline function but it takes a lot time again. I am posting the code in my question. Could you check it and advice?

Comment: @Joro - Yes. The `SELECT` that takes 3 seconds. Is that parallel? The other possibility might be that the one that inserts to the table orders by `ProductID` as that is the PK and that causes the issue.

Comment: @MartinSmith It is not the PrimaryKey - I try with it and without it in order to find my problem. The "Select" execution plan was parallel too :-] The problem now is that I have some issues with rewriting my code in inline function.

Comment: @Joro - You might find that in your inline version the CTE (that was previously evaluated once and stored in a table variable) is getting repeatedly re-evaluated. If that is the case then you could try adding a `TOP (Some_Large_Number) ..... ORDER BY Something` to the definition to encourage SQL Server to materialise it once into a spool.

Comment: @MartinSmith I am sorry, could you show me a example of what you mean?I am not very good with the use of CTE.

Comment: @Joro - [As per the example on this Connect Item](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/218968/). So something like `WITH CTE(ProtoSurveyID,ProductID) AS (SELECT DISTINCT TOP (2147483647) CAST(B.ProtoSurveyID AS INT), CAST(A.Col002 AS NVARCHAR(25)) FROM ... ORDER BY B.ProtoSurveyID`